# How to populate Spinner with phone contacts

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, spinner, contacts

I'm trying to develop an app for Android using Xamarin Studio.
My application includes it's custom sms sending feature. I have followed instructions that I found [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/sms/send_an_sms/). My app stores the text of an sms in a string that I can send using SmsManager, but that's only if I indicate the recipient number from within the code.

I can create an editText field where user can input the number and my app will parse the input to send the sms to the specified number. But I want users to be able to do this easily. So I thought of adding a Spinner and populating it with contacts from the user's phone. So how do I do this?

When the user clicks on the Spinner, they'd get a droplist of their contacts and they could select who they want to send the sms to. Then when they'd click the "Send" button, app would parse the number of the currently selected contact from the Spinner and send my sms to that number.

If possible, can you provide an example of how this could be done programatically?

Thanks, in advance.

Edit:
I have tried following [this article](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/contentproviders/read_contacts/) to be able to read from contacts, but I ran into two problems here:

1. Where would these contacts be stored in my app? Would they be listed in the textView?
2. I can not run my app using this code.

Here's what I've done: I opened up Xamarin Studio. Started up a new project. As you know, when you start a new project in Xamarin it automatically creates a simple app with a single button that counts how many times it was clicked. I didn't delete this button and it's code since this really shouldn't be interfering with anything. Then I proceeded to copy-paste the code from the article I mentioned before. So here's how my code looks like now:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Provider;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tabletApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "tabletApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon =     "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : ListActivity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

            string[] projection = {     ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName };

            var cursor = ManagedQuery (uri, projection, null, null, null);

            var contactList = new List<string> ();

            if (cursor.MoveToFirst ()) {
                do {
                    contactList.Add (cursor.GetString (
                        cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [1])));
                }  while (cursor.MoveToNext());
            }

            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this,
                Resource.Layout.ContactItemView, contactList);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
        
            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When I build it, it gives me a warning on

```
var cursor = ManagedQuery (uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

which says:

> 'Android.App.Activity.ManagedQuery(Android.Net.Uri, string[], string, string[], string)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

And when I try to run it on my Emulator it gives me this error:

> A Java.Lang.RuntimeException was thrown.
>
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.tabletapp/md58d10de2bb92bb56e56e9e7d7c4f55d68.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

I tried to look this error up and the suggestions were to change previous "@+id/list" to "@android:id/list" in the properties of the textView in .axml file. My file didn't even contain "@+id/list" in it's textView's properties. I tried adding "@android:id/list", but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: @Blackwood I have edited my post to give more specifications.